# Can a word "it" be used to refer to a person as well?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) 
>   [Is it appropriate to refer to a person of unknown sex by “it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56567/is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-a-person-of-unknown-sex-by-it)

If so, could anyone give an example pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost never appropriate to use *it* for a person.  Sometimes, we seem to use *it* when asking about somebody's gender.  E.g.:

> A: My wife's had a baby!
>
> B: Is **it** a boy or a girl?
>
> A: **It**'s a boy!

but here *it* is just a [dummy pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).

If you don't know the gender, you have the following options:

1. Use an arbitray gender and stick to it (usually *he*).
2. Use *he / she*.
3. Use *they*.  (This is the most "natural" way for native English speakers, although some consider it a little informal.)
4. Use a descriptive noun.  E.g. *the customer*.

Note that it is very offensive to refer to transexuals, transvestites, hermaphrodites, and so on as **it**.  If the person adopts a male name, use *he*.  If the person adopts a female name, use *she*.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clear answer. What if I use "it" to something informal such as in the phrase: "Pry it." Would it be safe or appropriate to assume that the "it" could also mean an object, a place, or a person?

Comment: You're welcome!  :-)  But I don't understand your "Pry it." question.

Comment: =) Pry means to examine carefully. I'd like to be able to convey that when I say "pry it", the "it" would mean anything. It's actually fancy name of a category in my blog where I can post anything that I'd like to examine but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Well, since it's a general category, "it" is fine, but I think "Pry" is wrong for two reasons. First, when this meaning of *pry* takes an object you need the word *into*. ("Pry into it") Second, when you pry into things, you are doing more than just examining closely: you are trying to find secrets. It has negative connotations. "Prying into" somebody's life is usually a bad thing. Check http://wordnik.com/words/pry for examples of sentences. I don't know exactly what you plan to do on your blog, but maybe "Analyze it" or "Examine it" would be better than "Pry into it".

Comment: Poor example, because in neither of the sentences does the *it* refer to the baby. Much rather, it's a [dummy pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining) that doesn't depend on the rest of the sentence or the gender of the subject at hand. Compare: "There's a stranger in our backyard!" — "Is **it** a woman or a man?" — "**It's** a man."

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Thanks!  That's a good point.  I'll alter my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Pry" is a bad example. You don't pry (or pry into) a person, you pry a thing or an event. You wouldn't say either, "Pry Fred" or "Pry into Fred". You might say "Pry into Fred's life" or "Pry into the incident where Fred disappered for a week". I suppose you could come up with hypothetical examples where the same word could apply to both a person and a thing, like you can "lose your child"  (in a crowd, e.g.) and you can also "lose your car keys". But if you said, "Have you lost something important?" and the person replied, "Yes, my wife", I think we'd take that as a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "it" refers to an object. A person is usually referred to by "he", "she", "him", "her", etc. A gender neutral way is to use "they" or "them, even for singles.

Examples:

"John is dirty, ***it*** hasn't taken a bath in days."

"John is dirty, ***he*** hasn't taken a bath in days."

Comment: "She was holding the baby, cradling it and smiling into its face."